# TFS Copy Files action exclude syntax

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to understand the logic behind TFS 2013 Copy Files action's Content filter syntax. I have a simple solution with a couple of projects and some test projects, which unfortunately have huge test files. I don't want the test projects or the files in the drop folder. Test projects are named like Project.Test, Project2.Test etc.

I tried to filter them like this:

```
**\bin\$(BuildPlatform)\$(BuildConfiguration)\**;-:**\*.Test\**
```

But this doesn't copy anything.

Test files are located in directories called TestFiles.

This also filters out everything:

```
**\bin\$(BuildPlatform)\$(BuildConfiguration)\**;-:**\TestFiles\**
```

If the first part matches the correct files in bin directory, how can the second part them filter them out? I don't see how that can match the same files.

Comment: You should update to TFS 2017 as there are significant improvement in build and release.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to my problem was to use a different syntax to exclude certain directories (*.Test here):

```
**\!(*.Test)\bin\$(BuildPlatform)\$(BuildConfiguration)\**
```